# select tag position varied while changing the attribute size

Tags: jquery, html

Here i put the code for the select tag without proper alignments between the two select tags.

The position of the select tag with the attribute size 2 doesnot match the select tag whose attribute size is 2 or more than 2.
    how to solve it?

```
<select id="name" >
<option value="">select all</option>
<option value="1">Text 1</option>
<option value="2">Text 2</option>
<option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>


<select id="name2">
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

I could able to find the padding or margins around the select tag.

```
// jQuery code to change the size dynamically

$(function() {  
  $('#name2').change(function(){
    $('#name').prop('selectedIndex',0);

  });


  $('#name').change(function(){
    $('#name2').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    $('#name2').attr('size',2);
  });

});
```

Here i put the code for the select tag without proper alignments between the two select tags.
The position of the select tag with the attribute size 2 does not match the select tag whose attribute size is 2 or more than

http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/654/

Comment: What is your expected outcome? It sounds to me like you're changing one of them but expecting them both to be the same?

Comment: couldnot you find out the difference between the select tag automatically  shrinks bottom by  5px.

Comment: I am not explaining about the size of the select tag, i am just explaining the moving of select tag from bottom to top by 5px when changing the attribute size.

Comment: What browser and OS are you seeing this on?

Comment: Chrome and Windows 7.

Comment: could you send the email id i will send you the screenshots.

Comment: Add the images to your question

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/126964192@N08/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `vertical-align: bottom;` to the select

```js
$(function() {
  $('#name2').change(function() {
    $('#name').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  });

  $('#name').change(function() {
    $('#name2').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    $('#name2').attr('size', 3);
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="name">
  <option value="">select all</option>
  <option value="1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="2">Text 2</option>
  <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>


<select id="name2">
  <option value="">select all</option>
  <option value="1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="2">Text 2</option>
  <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```